# How to have two table side by side in a two column paper?

Tags: tables, two-column

I have a two column paper. In one specific page, I intend to have two tables side by side, with no gap (or a very tiny gap) in between. Following image is what I am looking for:

[image]

I have used different approaches, but all were rendered in a scrambled way. For example:

```
\begin{table*}
\begin{minipage}[b]{\linewidth}
 \centering
 \begin{tabular}{|| *6{c} ||}
 % some content
 \end{tabular}
 \end{minipage}
 \qquad
 \begin{minipage}[b]{\linewidth}
  \centering
 \begin{tabular}{|| *5{c} ||}
 % some content
 \end{tabular}
 \end{minipage}
\end{table*}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was working on something similar to what Fran has just posted.  Same basic idea with some embellishments.  The missing piece is to connect the vertical lines through the horizontal rules.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[table]{xcolor}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\setlength\doublerulesep{0.5pt}
\begin{tabular}{|| >{\sffamily}c || *5{>{\sffamily}c} || *5{>{\sffamily}c} ||}
\multicolumn{1}{c}{}& \multicolumn{5}{c}{\sffamily Table 1} & \multicolumn{5}{c}{\sffamily Table 1}\\
\hline\hline
\rowcolor{gray!25} No. & C1 & C2 & C3 & C4 & C5 & C1 & C2 & C3 & C4 & C5 \\
\hline\hline
1  & & & & & & & & & &  \\ \hline
2  & & & & & & & & & &  \\ \hline
3  & & & & & & & & & &  \\ \hline
4  & & & & & & & & & &  \\ \hline
5  & & & & & & & & & &  \\
\hline\hline
 \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, it works and the result is very good.

Answer (score 1):

Unnecessarily complicated:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{table*}
 \centering
 \begin{tabular}{|| *6{c} ||}
 x &  x & x & x & x & x \\
 \end{tabular}%
 \begin{tabular}{*5{c} ||}
 x & x & x & x & x \\
 \end{tabular}
\end{table*}
\end{document}
```

But even easier:  two tables side by side, with no gap, is one table.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{table*}
 \centering
 \begin{tabular}{|| *6{c} || *5{c} ||}
 x & x & x & x & x & x & x & x & x & x & x \\
 \end{tabular}
\end{table*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for the helpful solutions...